# Can weighted importance sampling be applied to off-policy evaluation for continuous state space MDPs?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, off-policy-methods, importance-sampling

Can weighted importance sampling (WIS) and importance sampling (IS) be applied to off-policy evaluation for continuous state spaces MDPs?

Given that I have trajectories of $(s_t,a_t)$ pairs and the behavior policy distribution $\pi_b(a_t | s_t)$ can be approximated with a neural network.

A [paper](http://incompleteideas.net/papers/MHS-WISnips2014.pdf) I came across where they say that IS can be used for continuous states whereas WIS cannot be used for function approximation. I am not sure why WIS cannot be applied to the continuous case whereas IS can be. Both of these techniques seem similar.